# Uber-api (UberEats) to update menu

Tags: uber-api

I have developed a POS system and I would like to access the uber-api to update the uber online menu dynamically. Our clients make some changes to their menu daily (based on what's available and fresh locally, holiday specials, other specials...). Also sometime we run out of an item and need to update the menu for this.

Is there an uber-api to update the menu and have it take effect immediately? (or almost immediately).

-George

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old. But you can do it now - [docs here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v2/put-eats-stores-storeid-menus)

Answer (score 0):

There is no UberEats publicly available API currently.

Comment: I know this is old. But is there a publicly available API for uberEats? or any alternatives? So that it will be really helpful to integrate uberEats orders into existing POS systems and things get lot easier rather than having multiple POS systems to do same job.